# How to install centos 7 , 32 bit version

Tags: virtualbox, iso-image, redhat-enterprise-linux, centos-7

I have found this link for centos 7 . 32 version. but could not work out how to install from this content.

http://buildlogs.centos.org/centos/7/os/i386/

I have made a iso of these files , but virtualbox says " no bootable media found "

Kindly suggest how to install this version on virtual box

Comment: why negative marking is given to this question. whats wrong with the question. ???

Comment: Just packaging files to an `.iso` file doesn’t make it bootable.

Comment: @melebius , would you mind in helping me how to make it bootable ???

Comment: Sorry, I’m not experienced in it. I could only google it just as you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't the bootable ISOs. The bootable ISOs are in
http://buildlogs.centos.org/centos/7/isos/i386/

Comment: thanks for this link , I am trying it .. before i make your answer as approved

Comment: it worked but its not stable version yet